# Boolean query parameter being treated as string by Sails.js

Tags: javascript, sails.js

My 'user' model (table) has an attribute (column) named 'active' of `type: 'boolean'`. While querying the Blueprint API:

CASE 1: `http://localhost:1337/user?active=true`

returns no data. However,

CASE 2: `http://localhost:1337/user?active=1`

behaves the desired way.

I tried tracing the request, but couldn't go beyond [actionUtil.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil.js). The `where` returns `{active: 'true'}` in case 1 and `{active: '1'}` in case 2. It's strange that the number as a string gets converted to number (1) but boolean as a string does not. Since the ORM has generated this column with type `tinyint(1)`, I am sure there is '1' to 1 conversion happening somewhere. I just need to add another conversion for boolean to 0/1. Any help?

If anyone could explain the request trace, that'd be really great! I don't know where the `exec()` function in [find.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/find.js) is defined.

Answer (score 3):

> I am sure there is '1' to 1 conversion happening somewhere.

Yup--in Javascript.  Fire up your Javascript console and try:

```
"1" == true
"0" == false 
"true" == true
"false" == false
```

The first two will return `true`.  The second two will return `false`.

If you're going to use blueprints with querystrings, you're going to have to deal with the fact that everything in the querystring is a string.  That means using `1` and `0` instead of `true` and `false`, among other things (like being careful with `===`).

Comment: Honestly I wasn't aware of this. So thank you. However, I was referring to the conversion during MySQL query formation. Which brings us to another thing I learnt: MySQL doesn't distinguish between '1' and 1. Isn't that weird, considering the column type is defined to be `tinyint`?

Comment: Weird is in the eye of the beholder, I suppose, but in this case it's [pretty well documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)...

Comment: Yea, ultimately it's just a pidgeonhole issue: Javascript basically has five types that make sense in the database: Number, String, Boolean, Array, and Object. Databases can have hundreds of types, custom types, you name it. So any `5-->(n > 5)` mapping will involve some weirdness here and there.